Cannot access ipv6 but interface has an ipv6 address
My wireless interface has both an ipv4 and an ipv6 address, but I can only ping on ipv4. It looks like the ipv6 neighborhood is empty. Is there a way to restore it? Or is it possible that ipv6 has been disabled somewhere in the network configuration?
R!fedora:/root
> ip address show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlp0s20f3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 48:68:4a:2b:fc:23 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.133.50/24 brd 192.168.133.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp0s20f3
       valid_lft 2614sec preferred_lft 2614sec
    inet6 fe80::72c4:6a4f:3b8a:6475/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
9: ppp0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1354 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 3
    link/ppp 
    inet 192.168.253.28 peer 87.190.63.70/32 scope global ppp0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

R!fedora:/root
> ip -6 neigh

R!fedora:/root
> ip -4 neigh
192.168.133.1 dev wlp0s20f3 lladdr d8:0d:17:c0:0f:d3 REACHABLE 

R!fedora:/root
> ip -6 route show
fe80::/64 dev wlp0s20f3 proto kernel metric 1024 pref medium

R!fedora:/root
> sysctl net.ipv6.neigh.default
net.ipv6.neigh.default.anycast_delay = 100
net.ipv6.neigh.default.app_solicit = 0
net.ipv6.neigh.default.base_reachable_time_ms = 30000
net.ipv6.neigh.default.delay_first_probe_time = 5
net.ipv6.neigh.default.gc_interval = 30
net.ipv6.neigh.default.gc_stale_time = 60
net.ipv6.neigh.default.gc_thresh1 = 128
net.ipv6.neigh.default.gc_thresh2 = 512
net.ipv6.neigh.default.gc_thresh3 = 1024
net.ipv6.neigh.default.interval_probe_time_ms = 5000
net.ipv6.neigh.default.locktime = 0
net.ipv6.neigh.default.mcast_resolicit = 0
net.ipv6.neigh.default.mcast_solicit = 3
net.ipv6.neigh.default.proxy_delay = 80
net.ipv6.neigh.default.proxy_qlen = 64
net.ipv6.neigh.default.retrans_time_ms = 1000
net.ipv6.neigh.default.ucast_solicit = 3
net.ipv6.neigh.default.unres_qlen = 101
net.ipv6.neigh.default.unres_qlen_bytes = 212992

Here's an attempt to actually access the ipv6 net:
R!fedora:/root
> ping -6 www.google.com
ping: connect: Le réseau n'est pas accessible

R!fedora:/root
> ping -4 www.google.com
PING www.google.com (142.250.186.68) 56(84) octets de données.
64 octets de fra24s05-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.186.68) : icmp_seq=1 ttl=116 temps=27.9 ms
64 octets de fra24s05-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.186.68) : icmp_seq=2 ttl=116 temps=38.8 ms
^C
--- statistiques ping www.google.com ---
2 paquets transmis, 2 reçus, 0% packet loss, time 1002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 27.897/33.339/38.782/5.442 ms


You don't appear to have anything other than a link-local ipv6 address. You're not going to be able to access anything other than other link-local addresses unless you configure a routeable ipv6 address on that interface (e.g., using SLAAC or DHCPv6).

For the future - when posting things online, it's good to use English. Simply run LANG=C ping www.google.com to get everything in English. For better or worse English is the lingua franca of IT.
